# I would love to know the meaning of this script on a carved box given to me as a gift from a visitor to Singapore. (Characters identified: 珍藏)

Tags: translation, character-identification, transcription

This script is engraved on a carved box given to me as a gift Singapore. I would love to know the meaning of this script (pictures attached). Thanks in advance[image: box with engraved plate]
[image: engraved script]

Comment: A "Western" translation would be a "Lucky Keepsake"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It said: 珍藏

> **珍藏(n) precious/ cherished collection**

*珍藏 (v) to cherish and keep/ store*

*珍藏 (adj) cherished and kept/ stored*

Answer (score 1):

"珍藏" - save preciously, or treasure/collection, with the word "福(luck)" above and below.

It could be a gift for your friendship, or a fond memory - 情誼**珍藏**於心底 (Friendship saved preciously in the bottom of the heart).